# Python-splash: scrape site with JS next button

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, splash-screen

My goal is to click "Next button" on the page.
The main problem - next button goes without url, only javascript.

Could somebody show me the right way to solve my problem:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cruises"
    start_urls = ["https://www.msccruises.com/en-gl/Plan-Book/Find-Cruise.aspx"]

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 0.5})

def parse(self, response):

    lua_src = """
    function main(splash) 
        splash:go(splash.args.url)
        splash:wait(1)
        --splash:runjs("document.querySelectorAll('#mainContent_fycResults_rptPagination_btnPageNext')[0].click()")            
        splash:runjs("document.getElementsByClassName('btnPageNext')[0].click()")            
        splash:wait(1)
        page = splash:html()
        return page
    end"""

    next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="btnPageNext"]')
    if next_page is not None:
        url = "https://www.msccruises.com/en-gl/Plan-Book/Find-Cruise.aspx"
        yield SplashRequest(
            url,
            self.parse,
            endpoint='execute',
            method='POST',
            dont_filter=True,
            args={
                'wait': 1.0,
                'lua_source': lua_src,
            },
        )
```

Comment: Yes, I read this doc before!

Comment: I have modified my code (in f)... Now it's working without errors, but get first page in loop.